# How Do I Add SSL/TLS Connection Security Option to Evolution Mail?

Tags: email, evolution, ssl

As the title indicates, I am having trouble moving one of my mail accounts from Thunderbird to Evolution Mail because the mail server where my email is located will only accept a SSL connection.  Thunderbird's 'SSL/TLS' default connection security option works perfectly, but Evolution Mail only provides 'STARTTLS after connecting' and 'TLS on a dedicated port' as connection security options.  Can someone dummy-proof instructions on how to get my Evolution mail to support SSL connections?

Ubuntu 18.04

Evolution 3.28.5

Can't find a single thing explaining why SSL support is NOT by default built into Evolution.  Even Evolution's own help docs say that SSL is supported, but the actual option for SSL connection simply is not there.

I uninstalled evolution, installed the PPA, and re-installed.  There is no option for SSL connection security... banging head on wall... now.

This is what I see:
[image]

[image]

**NOTE:** I have tried all three Security Encryption Methods, but none work.

Thanx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**You already have that option**, it's just named differently between Thunderbird and Evolution.

Thunderbird's "SSL/TLS" option is equivalent to Evolution's "TLS on a dedicated port".
Use the port and "TLS on a dedicated port" options to emulate Thunderbird's "SSL/TLS" options.

Under the hood they both say that it's a dedicated port that only accepts TLS connections by default, rather than StartTLS which starts on a plaintext connection and then upgrades to TLS Encrypted automatically after the initial connection is established.

---

**But, why is "SSL" not listed?**

"SSL" and "TLS" are two protocols that do encrypted connectivity but with different handshake mechanisms, etc.  "SSL" died effectively when SSLv3 was effectively killed by the POODLE vulnerability in 2014, and is effectively considered "dead" now.  TLS is now the *protocol* that is supported for encrypted connections.

However, "SSL" itself has such a known history in terms of being discussed as the "encryption mechanism" and "SSL Certificates" and such that "SSL" and "TLS" are synonymous for "TLS" nowadays in the average person's vocabulary and such.  Whenever we say "SSL" we usually mean "TLS" nowadays though.

(And since OpenSSL versions in 18.04 and later have SSLv2 and SSLv3 disabled by default, SSL is effectively dead, but TLS lives on)

Comment: I tried exactly that... did not work...  I will edit my post to reflect that.  But thanks for taking a shot.... same email works perfectly in Thunderbird

Comment: ♦  I am going to vote up your answer... It appears that my problem is actually on the mail server and not a problem with Evolution connection security options.  How do I know??  On my last attempt to configure the account, I used the settings you suggested.. then went and started doing other work...slowly the settings  "kicked in" and downloaded my mail. So then, I added my second mail on the same server and got an ERROR.  So, I am simply leaving the settings as they are and hoping that the mail server updates whatever internal settings, as it did with my first account.

Comment: @yupthatguy Yeah, some mail servers have different configurations, so you'll need to refer to the configurations for each server.  Not all of them have the same configurations unfortunately.

Comment: ♦ All progress that I reported literally vanished overnight.  Instead of the second email account downloading my mail like the first account eventually did, using the same settings.  This morning I find that now my first account "regressed". 
 Both accounts give me this error "The reported error was “Failed to select mailbox: SELECT Unsafe Login."  NOTE: before I slept last night, I dscovered eveen though the first account downloaded the complete folder structure and mail headers to my machine, I could not actually open a message and read it. FRUSTRATION :-(

Comment: OK, green tea kicking in.  Thought:  I know you said SSLv3 is "dead", but apparently it is still available in Thunderbird 68.10.0 .  Is there a way that I can add SSLv3 to Evolution so that I can dependably get my mail?

Comment: @yupthatguy its effectively dead is what I said.  MOST systems for mail are not using SSLv3 anymore since the POODLE breach and due to many policy compliance rules requiring it to be off.

Comment: As for your unsafe login that is beyond my scope to debug in this question as that is a completely different error/issue and is obscured by your encryption types context menu drop-down :P